# Bootstrap website in Dreamweaver

Tags: css, navbar

I have a bootstrap web page editing in Dreamweaver.  On my drop-down menu, I would like the page that the user is currently on to be highlighted or shown in a different colour, in the drop-down menu.  The navigation bar is located in its own page and linked into the main site.
How can I make this happen?

This is what I currently have in main.css:

```
ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu{
display: block;    
}

.nav-header{
color:#800;
margin-left: -10px;
}

.active > a, .nav > .active > a {
color: white;
background-color: #0A0A0A;
}

.active > a, .nav > .active > a:hover {
color: white;
background-color: maroon;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle of your problem?

Comment: You need to add the `active` class to the `<a>` in question with the user is on that page. Also this has nothing to do with Dreamweaver or any other editor you might be using.

Comment: You must add the `.active` class with a dynamic language like PHP or Javascript.

Comment: Sounds like you need JS to detect which page you are on and apply the active class to that link. CSS can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML file you need to add the .active class to your links parent element that is associated to the page you are currently on, since your `CSS` is using the child selector `>` which means it will look for the `<a>` tag inside of the `.active` class. For example if you are on the about us page you would need to add the class to the about us link parent element like below:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home Page</a><li>
    <li class="active" ><a href="about-us.html">About Us</a><li>
</ul>
```

or if the navigation is in its own file and is reused on all of your pages you can do it with `PHP's` `basename()` function and `$_SERVER[]` superglobal.

```
<?php $currentPage = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>
<ul>
  <li <?php if($currentPage == "index.php") { echo "class='active'"; } ?>><a href="index.php" >Home Page</a></li>
  <li <?php if($currentPage == "about-us.php") { echo "class='active'"; }?>><a href="about-us.php" >About Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

with the `PHP` solution above, the `basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);` gets the name of the current page you are on from the `URL` then inside the navigation markup it checks to see if the current page you are on is equal to the name of the file associated with that link. If it is then it puts the `class="active"` on that links parent element.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I don't have any PHP files so would I need to add this or can I put some code into the js script? 
Thanks